# List assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have lists like this,

```
a=['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
b=['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
c=['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 1']
```

Here I am trying to replace each element of list 'a' one by one with the element of list 'c'.
I tried this code:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i]=c[i]
    print a
    a=['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
```

With this code I am getting correct output which is:

```
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 1']
```

But when I replaced the last statement(assigning) as

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i]=c[i]
    print a
    a=b
```

list 'b' also updating. How can i achieve this with out assigning the entire list directly.

Comment: You keep putting back the old value of `a` with `a=['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the last line with:

```
a=b[:]
```

Comment: i am getting error as ,TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: its working for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [copy](http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php) moduel in python

```
from copy import deepcopy
a = deepcopy(b)
```

Comment: Thank you, its worked for me.

Comment: @sowji : Most Welcome..If its help you, then appreciate answer by upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

Really unsure of what it is you are asking but seems to me you are trying to achieve something like:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i]=c[i] # change only the specified itemnr of list a with the same itemnr of list c.  
    print a # prints (as you've seen and mentioned to be correct: list a with one of its items replaced by an item of list c)
    a[i]=b[i] # Since list a[i] has been set to c[i] earlier in the loop doesn't mean it can't be changed again in the same loop.
    print a
```

Output:

```
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 1']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
```

Or, if you want to process list `b` similar to `a` you could also simply do (since list b has the exact same length as a):

```
for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i]=c[i] 
        print a 
        b[i]=c[i]
        print b
```

Output:

```
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 1']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 1']
```

Or you could do:

```
for x in [a,b]:
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i]=c[i]
        print(x)
```

Output:

```
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 1']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 0', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967295', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 0']
['name test', 'maximum-net-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-expected-throughput 1', 'maximum-gamma-data-rate 4294967296', 'minimum-gamma-data-rate 1']
```